# Using Pandoc to read Docx, to capture contents of a docx textbox

Tags: metadata, docx, pandoc

When I use Pandoc to read a docx file, it ignores textboxes.They do not seem to be copied to the intermediary format.

How can I make pandoc read the textbox into the intermediary format, so that I can write a filter to include it in the output?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the maintainer of the docx reader in pandoc. I don't think it currently deals with text boxes -- and I'm not sure there's an elegant way to represent them in pandoc's intermediate format. But if you post an issue on [pandoc's github issue tracker](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues), along with a sample docx file, I'll take a look and see if it's possible to add it to the reader.

Comment: OK, I have raised a request on the pandoc docx issue tracker. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3086]